# How to output predicted values as a string in excel?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

so I was able to output my predicted numerical values into an excel file but I was wondering if it is possible to instead of the numerical value, it actual exports the string instead.

Currently it looks like this,

| Column 1 | Answer Key | Predicted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Something Something | Cars | 3 |

Instead of it returning 3, I would like for 3 be replaced as the actual string its associated with (for example, idk Truck).

here is my code so far, I know I have to mess with the exporting part of the code but I cannot seem to figure this out.

```
texts = df['without_Tags'].astype('str')

vector = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df = 2, max_df = .95)
X = vector.fit_transform(texts) #features

LE = LabelEncoder()
df['tower_values'] = LE.fit_transform(df['Tower'])
y = df['tower_values'].values

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

lsa = TruncatedSVD (n_components=100, n_iter=10, random_state=3)

X = lsa.fit_transform(X)
print(X.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .3, shuffle = True, stratify = y, random_state = 3)

SG = SGDClassifier(random_state=3, loss='log')
SG.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = SG.predict(X_test)

print("SG model accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("SG model Recall:", recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))
print("SG model Precision:", precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))
print("SG model F1 Score:", f1_score(y_test, y_pred, average="macro"))


y_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv')

final = pd.read_csv('prediction.csv')
final['pre'] = y_pred
df.to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Have you made any researches?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864695/saving-prediction-results-to-csv I tried this but it only gives me the numerical value of the y_pred. There is other tutorials I tried but I cant seem to find the right one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using inverse transform method of `LabelEncoder()`

```
y_pred = LE.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

Comment: I think this working. Is it possible to also show the target column next to my output?

Comment: y_pred = LE.inverse_transform(y_pred)
prediction = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('prediction.csv') this is what I have so far

Comment: Yes, You can . Do not directly convert it to csv. Add another column after `prediction = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=['predictions'])` like `prediction["target"] = df['Tower']` after convert it to csv like `prediction.to_csv('prediction.csv')`

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. I got it to work. By any chance do you know how to instead of returning only 30% of the data set, it returns the whole thing.

Comment: Oh Sorry. Use `target_values = LE.inverse_transform(y_test)` and then use `prediction["target"] = target_values`